# найти количество уникальных чисел в массиве java

Tags: java

Напишите метод `uniqueCount`, который будет находить количество уникальных чисел в массиве. Если число повторяется больше одного раза, то его стоит учитывать, но только один раз. Длина массива > 0.

Пример:

> Входящие данные  {11, 12, 10, 5, 4, 44, 100, 44, 11, 10, 11}
>
> Ответ 7
>
> Объяснение
>   Массив без повторений будет выглядеть 4, 5, 10, 11, 12,
>   44, 100 - длина 7.

Помогите с решением задачи.

Мой вариант:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {11, 12, 10, 5, 4, 44, 100, 44, 11, 10, 11, 3};
    System.out.println(uniqueCount(array));
}

static int uniqueCount(int[] array) {
    int result = 0;
    int countUnique = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        countUnique++;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] == array[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result = countUnique - count;
}
```

Но ответ на единицу меньше, чем должен быть. Не понимаю где ошибка моя. Наверное неправильно задаю `j`, откуда начинать сравнивать элементы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш алгоритм не учитывает, что числа могут повторяться больше, чем два раза - `11` в Вашем случае.

```
for (int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) 
{
   if (array[j] == array[i])
   { 
     count++; 
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вы мне очень помогли. )))

Comment: @YuriiS Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Answer (score 3):

Можно решить через множество, которое исключает возможность иметь дубликаты:

```
int[] array = {11, 12, 10, 5, 4, 44, 100, 44, 11, 10, 11, 3};
System.out.println(array.length); // 12

Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<>();
for (int x : array) {
    mySet.add(x);
}
System.out.println(mySet.size()); // 8
```

Или аналогично через список и проверку наличия элемента:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int x : array) {
    if (!myList.contains(x))
        myList.add(x);
}
System.out.println(myList.size()); // 8
```

---

Ну если обернуть один из алгоритмов в функцию:

```
static int uniqueCount(int[] array) {
    Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<>();
    for (int x : array) {
        mySet.add(x);
    }
    return mySet.size();
}
...

int[] array = {11, 12, 10, 5, 4, 44, 100, 44, 11, 10, 11, 3};
System.out.println(array.length); // 12
System.out.println(uniqueCount(array)); // 8
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я только начинаю изучать программирование и язык java. Списки ещё не проходили, поэтому мой вариант решения данной задачи выглядит таким громоздким.

Comment: @YuriiS, успехов :)

Comment: Вас ждут [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11448/176217).

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант без использования коллекций или библиотек:

```
public class x {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[]x = new int[]{1,1,1,2,2,2,1,3,1,2,5,4};
        System.out.println(uniqueCount(x));
    }
    public static int uniqueCount(int[]array){

        int[] copy = new int[array.length];
        int res = 0;
        int countNum = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <copy.length ; i++) {
            copy[i] = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (copy[i]==0){
                for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                    if (array[i]==array[j]){
                        copy[j] = 1;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (countNum<count){
                countNum = count;
                res++;
            }

        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 O(array.length + max_num) ~ O(n+const)           

int histo [] = new int [max_num];
            int [] array = int[] array = {11, 12, 10, 5, 4, 44, 100, 44, 11, 10, 11, 3};
            for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++)histo[array[i]]++;
    int summ = 0
    for(int i =0; i < histo.length;i++){
    num = histo[i];
    if(num >0) summ++;
    }

System.out.println(summ);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class Z2{
public static void main(String[] args){
String mass[]=new String[5];
String mass2[]=new String[5];
int kol=0,kol_tmp=0;
Random rnd=new Random();
//Заполнение массива mass случайными числами
for(int i=0;i<=mass.length-1;i++){
    mass[i]=String.valueOf(rnd.nextInt(1));

}
//Подсчёт количества
for(int i=0;i<=mass.length-1;i++){
    kol_tmp=0;
    for(int j=0;j<=mass.length-1;j++){
        if(mass[i].equals(mass2[j]))
            kol_tmp++;
    }
    if(kol_tmp==0){
    mass2[kol]=mass[i];
    kol++;
    }
}

//Вывод массива1
 System.out.println("mass");
for(int i=0;i<=mass.length-1;i++){
    System.out.print(mass[i]+" ");
}
System.out.println("");

//Вывод массива2
 System.out.println("mass2");
for(int i=0;i<=mass.length-1;i++){
    System.out.print(mass2[i]+" ");
}
System.out.println("\nКоличество различных элементов ="+kol);
}
}
```